# Unexpected behavior when using recur in a variadic function

Tags: clojure

I was writing an answer for [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142758/pandigital-doubling) challenge, when I needed to give a recursive function an optional parameter. I ended up with something kind of equivalent to:

```
(defn func [a & [b?]]
  (if b?
    b?
    (recur a a)))
```

My intent was for `b?` to act as an optional parameter. If it wasn't supplied, it would be defaulted to `nil` via destructuring.

Instead of running though, it gave me an error:

```
(func 1)
UnsupportedOperationException nth not supported on this type: Long  clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:947)
```

After some debugging, I realized that for some reason the rest parameter wasn't a list as I'd expect, but just the passed number! The error was coming about because it tried to destructure the number.

I can fix it by getting rid of the wrapper list in the parameter list:

```
(defn func [a & b]
  ...
```

But this just looks wrong. I know the rest parameter *should* be a list, but `b` is actually just a number. If I use "unoptimized" recursion, it works as I'd expect:

```
(defn func2 [a & [b?]]
  (if b?
    b?
    (func2 a a)))

(func2 1)
=> 1
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a [known difference](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur#example-55ff3cd4e4b08e404b6c1c7f)

```clj
; Note that recur can be surprising when using variadic functions.

(defn foo [& args]
  (let [[x & more] args]
    (prn x)
    (if more (recur more) nil)))

(defn bar [& args]
  (let [[x & more] args]
    (prn x)
    (if more (bar more) nil)))

; The key thing to note here is that foo and bar are identical, except
; that foo uses recur and bar uses "normal" recursion. And yet...

user=> (foo :a :b :c)
:a
:b
:c
nil

user=> (bar :a :b :c)
:a
(:b :c)
nil

; The difference arises because recur does not gather variadic/rest args
; into a seq.
```

It's the last comment that describes the difference.

Comment: Oh, that's weird. I don't know how I've never noticed this before. Thanks.

Comment: This makes sense, if you think about it. If `recur` gathered "rest" arguments into a sequence you'd have to un-nest the passed-in sequence in order to recursively invoke the function, which would be a huge pain.